# Google Cloud SQL import from bucket : error 403

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-shell

I'd like to import sql data into my Cloud SQL database (named "db2").
Therefore I have uploaded a sql-file into my bucket.
Then I go to my Cloud SQL database and click on "connect with Cloud Shell".
When trying to import via CloudShell I get :

```
info@cloudshell:~ (servers)$ gcloud sql import sql db2 gs://mybucket/db.sql
Data from [gs://mybucket/db.sql] will be imported to [db2].
Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  Y
ERROR: (gcloud.sql.import.sql) HTTPError 403: The service account does not have the required permissions for the bucket.
```

I have followed the solution given to a somewhat same issue here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53608811/2795648
But this does not work for me.

The service account of my Cloud SQL database has ALL the permissions I can give on the bucket AND on the file (not that this is neccessary).

Some extra info added. Here are the rights of the service account :

```
- members:
  - serviceAccount:p3998516xxxxx-p9q5dn@gcp-sa-cloud-sql.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/storage.admin
- members:
  - serviceAccount:p3998516xxxxx-p9q5dn@gcp-sa-cloud-sql.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/storage.objectAdmin
- members:
  - serviceAccount:p3998516xxxxx-p9q5dn@gcp-sa-cloud-sql.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/storage.objectCreator
- members:
  - serviceAccount:p3998516xxxxx-p9q5dn@gcp-sa-cloud-sql.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/storage.objectViewer
- members:
  - serviceAccount:p3998516xxxxx-p9q5dn@gcp-sa-cloud-sql.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/storagetransfer.admin
- members:
  - serviceAccount:p3998516xxxxx-p9q5dn@gcp-sa-cloud-sql.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/storagetransfer.user
- members:
  - serviceAccount:p3998516xxxxx-p9q5dn@gcp-sa-cloud-sql.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/storagetransfer.viewer
```

Answer (score 3):

Here you find official documentation about [Importing a SQL dump file](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/importing)

Please pay attention to:

3.Describe the instance you are importing to:

```
gcloud sql instances list    
gcloud sql instances describe [INSTANCE_NAME]
```

4.Copy the serviceAccountEmailAddress field.

```
gcloud sql instances describe [INSTANCE_NAME] | grep serviceAccountEmailAddress
```

5.Use `gsutil` iam to grant the legacyBucketWriter and objectViewer Cloud IAM roles to the service account for the bucket.

```
gsutil iam ch serviceAccount:your_previous_service_account_step4:legacyBucketWriter,objectViewer gs://ex-bucket
```

Then try the import command:

```
gcloud sql import sql [INSTANCE_NAME] gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[IMPORT_FILE_NAME] \
                        --database=[DATABASE_NAME]
```

Comment: gcloud projects get-iam-policy project-id gives me :
- members:
  - serviceAccount:p399851xxxxxx-p9qxxx@gcp-sa-cloud-sql.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/storage.admin
- members:
  - serviceAccount:p399851xxxxxx-p9qxxx@gcp-sa-cloud-sql.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/storage.objectCreator
- members:
  - serviceAccount:p399851xxxxxx-p9qxxx@gcp-sa-cloud-sql.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/storage.objectViewer
Is this not enough then ?
Still getting the 403 error.

Comment: Your "gsutil iam ch" command gives error : AccessDeniedException: 403 info@mydomain.be does not have storage.buckets.getIamPolicy access to mybucket.

Comment: Hi, can you check if granting the role of [Storage Admin](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles#standard-roles) to info@mydomain.be solves this error?

Comment: @marian.valdoi, why is the legacyObjectWriter necessary? Why does it need write access?